# Write and read data in the same time with Android Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm using the Room Persistence Library,

when I write a large number of data in the DB, it is inaccessible, so I can't read any data from it.

Is there any way to write and read data at the same time efficiently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need write ahead of logging feature of sqlite, which according to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.JournalMode#AUTOMATIC is enabled on devices running api 16+, if you have trouble reading data while writing, it might be of a misuse of room, sharing a bit of your code might help

Comment: If you write to the DB successfully, it should be accessible; you probably are not accessing the data the right way or you're not even writing to the DB successfully.